# useTheme hook within className not working

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have the following within my `App.js` file:

```
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    bgCells: {
      textAlign: 'right',
      color: '#8ccadf',
      backgroundColor: '#eef7ff'
    }
  }
});
```

I then have another component `Report.js` where I would like to access `bgCells` within a className via the useTheme hook, i.e.:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TableCell, TableRow, useTheme } from '@mui/material';

export default function Report(props) {
  const { info } = props;
  const theme = useTheme();

let myClass;

if (info.is_active) {
    myClass = classes.someStyles;
} else {
    myClass = theme.palette.bgCells;
}

  return (
    <TableRow className={myClass}>
      <TableCell>
        {
          . . . .
```

Unfortuantely this is not working as `myClass = theme.palette.bgCells` is not being reference within my `<TableRow className={myClass}>`

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`palette` in `createTheme` is not the right place for styling. You should put only colors there.

`bgCells` is an object, you can not add object as className. className must be string.

You can style the component with object via `sx` prop

```
<TableRow sx={{textAlign: 'right', ...}}> ... </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your app with `ThemeProvider` from MaterialUI: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-provider